# Python - refering/redirecting to operator magic method of member attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, magic-methods

I've a question regarding overriding operator magic methods. I'm trying to provide the methods/attributes of `value` to the object `a` which holds that attribute. I would like to do so, because I have an application where `value` might be of changing type and it's not only limited to the add function. I could re-implement each magic method returning the return value of the corresponding magic method of `value`. Nevertheless, I was wondering whether it might work by re-implementing `__getattr__`.

Why does the example below raise an exception?
How does python call the `__add__` or `__radd__` method when `+` is used?
Is it possible to redirect that call without re-implementing `__add__`?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```py
class Attr:
    def __init__(self, value) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(name)
        except Exception as e:
            value = super().__getattribute__("value")
            return getattr(value, name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Attr(1)
    print("A:", a.value + 1)  # returns 2
    print("B:", getattr(a, "__add__")(1))  # returns 2
    print("C:", getattr(a, "__radd__")(1))  # returns 2
    print("D:", a.__add__(1))  # returns 2
    print("E:", a.__radd__(1))  # returns 2
    print("F:", a + 1)  # raises: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Attr' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with python objects, if you use the `+` operator, you're basically implying an addition, but those two are not numbers, that's why the error..

In your case here you have a type `Attr` and a type `int`, in this case you cannot add them directly. You cannot also convert the `Attr` to an int implicitly like so: `int(a)` because it is not a supported type for converting to integers

The `__add__()` function when used with objects and attributes, implicitly defines what you want to happen, which is **addition**